# Excel functions do not work properly after getting csv output from Pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, excel-formula, excel-2010

Recently, I confronted a very strange thing in Microsoft Excel. I made a dataframe in Python 3.6 and  filled it with some integer numbers, then I used "to_csv" function to get csv output. I opened the file with Microsoft Excel for doing basic statistical analysis and drawing some charts, however; Microsoft Excel doesn't recognize the numbers in the cells as number. For example, when I add two cell, the result will be zero, no matter what are the numbers.
This is a screenshot from my my Excel environment:
[image]

In the yellow cell (C101) I tried to get the sum of cells in column C, but as I explained the sum function (and all the other functions like Count or Max) doesn't work properly. I also, have to say, all the cells have "Number" data type. I'm quite confused, any suggestion would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I would have written the answer as a comment, but my reputation is too low.*

By default, the decimal seperator is set to a dot ('.'). You have to switch it to a comma (',') like this:

```
df.to_csv(file, decimal=',')
```

EDIT:

I forgot that you also have to set the seperator, since its default value is comma:

```
df.to_csv(file, sep=';', decimal=',')
```